# How can I set up enemies spawning in set locations in every level in my Unity game?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics

I'm new to Unity and I've made a game in which I can make the levels using prefabs quickly, but I found that making Enemies in prefabs isn't a good idea because they can't follow or interact with the player. What is the best way to make Enemies spawn as soon as the level generates without having to individually create every single one?

Player Code (or at least the instance variables without the methods):

```
public class PlayerPhys : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                          
[Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;          
[Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;
[SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = true;                         
[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                          
[SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;                           
[SerializeField] private Transform m_CeilingCheck;                          
[SerializeField] private Collider2D m_CrouchDisableCollider;                

const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f;
private bool m_Grounded;
const float k_CeilingRadius = .2f;
private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
private bool m_FacingRight = true;
private Vector3 m_Velocity = Vector3.zero;

[Header("Events")]
[Space]

public UnityEvent OnLandEvent;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

public BoolEvent OnCrouchEvent;
private bool m_wasCrouching = false;

private Animator m_Anim;

Transform playerGraphics;
```

Enemy prefab code I have so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 1;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Destroy this if killed
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Take damage
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
    }
}
```

I used [this Brackeys tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_Xp9pt8nRY&t=503s) to create levels, and all I'm confused about is how I can make it so that the level creator can create enemies which can interact with the player. I wish he went over how he made prefabricated coins able to be picked up by the player

Comment: What would prevent your enemies in prefabs from following or interacting with the player? That sounds like the root issue we should sort out.

Comment: Agree with DMG... sounds like a good use of prefabs to me.

Comment: why they not following / interacting with player? How are you making enemies now?

Comment: I'm guessing the enemies need a reference to the player object, and ScratchEnjoyer isn't sure how to assign that reference automatically either on start-up or when instantiating the prefab in the scene. It's hard to know for sure unless they edit their question to give us more details though.

Comment: @ScratchEnjoyer are you using tags? they are very useful in detecting who is player, who is enemy..

Comment: Like I said, I'm really new to Unity (started a few days ago), so I'm not completely sure how to phrase my question in a way that makes sense to experienced users. By interacting with the player, I meant following the player character or getting the player's location; is that not impossible with a prefab? How do I give prefabricated enemies a reference to the player object?

Comment: Also, how exactly could I use tags in this situation? Sorry if I'm asking really basic things

Comment: Please see my earlier message, @ScratchEnjoyer: "I'm guessing the enemies need a reference to the player object, and ScratchEnjoyer isn't sure how to assign that reference automatically either on start-up or when instantiating the prefab in the scene. It's hard to know for sure unless they **edit their question to give us more details** though." - Consider showing us your enemy script for starters, and a little information about how your player object is set up would help too.

Comment: @DMGregory Okay, I've added what code I have so far for both the player and the enemy

Comment: @ScratchEnjoyer The code you've shared does not include any code for trying to follow or interact with the player. Did you leave something out?

Comment: @Kevin I left out the code I originally had because I was told it can't possibly work, but the code I had in the Enemy class was along the lines of "GameObject.Find("Player")" etc. so that I could get the location of the player. This would normally work in a regular object but apparently not in prefabs

Comment: @ScratchEnjoyer It sounds like whoever said that doesn't know what they are talking about. Instances spawned from prefabs can certainly still use `GameObject.Find()`. On a side note, in general if you have to use `GameObject.Find()`, you should do it by type (e.g `GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>()`), not by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a reference to the player. I normally add to my scene an empty game-object called 'GAME_MANAGER' or similar. Attach to this a script with similar name GameManager.cs for example.

Inside GameManager.cs there are several ways we can get a reference to the player in the scene. Personally I like to spawn (ie. gameObject.Instantiate(playerPrefab)) the player in the GameManager. But I'll assume you have your player dragged into the scene so you don't have any reference. Well one way to make a reference to the existing player in the scene is to use Find (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

Here is a little example code:

GameManager.cs

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     PlayerPhys Player;

     void Start()
     {
         Player = GameObject.Find("EXACT PLAYER NAME").GetComponent<PlayerPhys>();
           
         // A different way is to FindObjectByType, it will return the first object it finds with a PlayerPhys component attached 
         Player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerPhys>();
     }
     
     
}
```

I also make my GameManager class a singleton. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/csharp/example

This way you can easily use this player reference from other scripts for example your enemies.

A very quick intro of how to make GameManager.cs into a singleton is as follows:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     public static GameManager singleton_instance;
     public PlayerPhys Player;

     void Start()
     {
         if (singleton_instance == null)
             singleton_instance =  this;
         else
             Destroy(this);
         Player = GameObject.Find("EXACT PLAYER NAME").GetComponent<PlayerPhys>();
     }
     
     
}
```

Disclaimer: I am not an expert. Just a indie game dev wannabe you has picked up tricks as I go. Others here can give much more technical and precise help/advice. That said if you have questions about what I wrote here, I will do my best to answer for you.

EDIT: An example of finding the player from within another script such as Enemy.cs:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
     void Update()
     {
          // ensure 'Player' in GameManager.cs is declared as public
          Vector3 player_position = GameManager.singleton_instance.Player.tranform.position;
     }
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying (summed up) is, I should create a Game Manager which is of type singleton, so that any object in the game can use it for reference? Can you give me an example line of code that I could write within the Enemy prefab code that would be able to obtain the Player variable from GameManager?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer. Hope it helps. If you get stuck ask some more and I will try to help (I'll be back online tomorrow)

Comment: My God you are a life saver. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're very welcome. It's nice for me to be the one helping someone here rather than the other way round every time :D

Comment: technically I think we haven't created a GameManager 'of type' singleton. What we did was add a public static reference to itself. It is of type GameManager. Also you will want to make sure you only ever have one GameManager which persists though all scenes. Don't really want to  have this spawning on every scene you make. But just keep playing and learning and when you get stuck again try to ask here another concise question about that specific problem if/when they arise. Happy coding!

Comment: You can use `FindObjectOfType<PlayerPhys>()` to avoid searching by name - [I recommend not searching by name whenever you can avoid it](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784). It also combines the search for the object and the search for the component into a single search.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory. I did include that in the code as a second option but wasn't sure if one was 'better' than the other.

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying, what about these lines of code I have inside of my pathfinding script?
public Transform target;

private void Awake() 
{
      Transform target = GameManager.singleton_instance.Player.transform;
}

Comment: Try using Start() instead of Awake(). Just a guess for now, as I say I am no expert. But that is another thing I remember catching me out using Awake(). I actually don't use Awake at all in my recent projects. If you really want to use Awake, maybe it will work by doing your 'instance = this' etc code in GameManager in Awake instead of Start

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying I don't know how you keep saving my life, you've been a great help lol

Comment: haha because I fell into all the same traps not too long ago :D